# Python MySql executemany error

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am getting an error on "cusrosr.executemany().
The first statements (with recs1) that inserts into a single column executes fine, and insets two records.
The second insert (recs2) has an error:

> not enough arguments for format string

```
sql="""CREATE  TABLE TestTable (
        Col1 VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
        Col2 VARCHAR(45) NULL );"""
cursor.execute(sql)

recs1=  [("Spam"), ("Ham")]
recs2=  [("Spam", "Sausage"), ("Ham", "Plate")]

try:
    cursor.executemany("""insert into TestTable (Col1) values (%s );""", recs1)
    db.commit()
    print "cursor.rowcount: ",cursor.rowcount
    cursor.executemany("""insert into TestTable (Col1, Col2) values (%s , %s);""", recs2)
    db.commit()

except Exception as e:
    print 'Error: ', e
    db.rollback()
```

- Software used:
- Python 2.7.4
- MySql installed from    MySQL-python-1.2.4b4.win32-py2.7. ('1.2.4b4')
- MySql '5.5.27-log' (on   AWS RDS).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your code, but just by looking at it, it looks you are feeding the string with two %s occurrences with just one value - hence the "not enough arguments for format string" error.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
recs2, recs3 =  [("Spam", "Sausage")], [("Ham", "Plate")]
cursor.executemany("""insert into TestTable (Col1, Col2) values (%s , %s);""", recs2, recs3)
```

Again, I haven't tested anything, so execute at your own risk.

Comment: That's the whole idea behind "executemany". See an example here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/myconnpy_MySQLCursor_executemany.html

Comment: Found a solution by replacing the MySql module with the original MySql mysql-connector-python-1.0.10-py2.7